# nginx - 301 redirect wrong URLs used on extern website

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

For some reason, some extern websites have links to my website subdomain.example.com looking something like this: `<a href="https://subdomain.example.com/https://subdomain.example.com/index.php?id=54597">Link</a>`

I cannot get these links corrected as I have no control over these links. So instead of showing a 404 error, I would like to redirect `https://subdomain.example.com/https://subdomain.example.com/index.php?id=54597` to `https://subdomain.example.com/index.php?id=54597` via nginx but I cannot get a location to match, once it includes a colon. Is there a way to get this to work?

something like

```
location ~ "^https://subdomain.example.com/index.php$" {
  return 301 /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All URIs in Nginx begin with a leading `/` and are normalised to remove consecutive `//`s.

You should change your regular expression to: `^/https:/subdomain\.example\.com/index\.php$` and place it **above** the `location` block which matches URIs ending with `.php`.

Alternatively, use an `=` operator to exactly match a single URI, for example:

```
location = /https:/subdomain.example.com/index.php {
    return 301 /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.